# Unity3D - Slice sprite at runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can I make 9-Slicing of sprite at runtime by using just Unity API?

StackOverflow asks me to add more words so :) I've found corresponding property (Sprite.border) but it's read only. Not much information about this can be found online.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Could you explain a bit further what exactly your goal is? `StackOverflow asks me to add more words` -> you should use them to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I needed to create 9-sliced texture and set it as background of my UI element. And I needed to make it at runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to slice sprite by script ?(not use Editor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55738954/how-to-slice-sprite-by-script-not-use-editor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create one by using [Sprite.Create](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html). It has a parameter called border.