# How to slice sprite by script ?(not use Editor)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I trying to slice Sprite(type casted to Texture2D) by script,

when project is running on Android or IOS Platform

is it possible by script??

I trying to use UnityEditor Class and it is work on Computer

but When I trying to Build Android or IOS It is failed.

```
    void OnPreprocessTexture()
    {
        TextureImporter textureImporter = (TextureImporter)assetImporter;
        textureImporter.textureType = TextureImporterType.Sprite;
        textureImporter.spriteImportMode = SpriteImportMode.Multiple;
        textureImporter.mipmapEnabled = false;
        textureImporter.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;

    }

    public void OnPostprocessTexture(Texture2D texture)
    {
        Debug.Log("Texture2D: (" + texture.width + "x" + texture.height + ")");



        int spriteSize = 350;
        int colCount = texture.width / spriteSize;
        int rowCount = texture.height / spriteSize;

        List<SpriteMetaData> metas = new List<SpriteMetaData>();

        for (int r = 0; r < rowCount; ++r)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < colCount; ++c)
            {
                SpriteMetaData meta = new SpriteMetaData();
                meta.rect = new Rect(c * spriteSize, r * spriteSize, spriteSize, spriteSize);
                meta.name = c + "-" + r;
                metas.Add(meta);
            }
        }

        TextureImporter textureImporter = (TextureImporter)assetImporter;
        textureImporter.spritesheet = metas.ToArray();
    }

    public void OnPostprocessSprites(Texture2D texture, Sprite[] sprites)
    {
        Debug.Log("Sprites: " + sprites.Length);
    }
```

It is not working When running project on Android or IOS

[What I want]

Procedure

During running on Android or IOS Platform

1) Receive some Images from server (Url or file)

2) Load Image on C# script

3) Change type Images to Texture or Sprite ect...

4) Slice Images(Don't use Editor)

5) Save Pieces of Image

6) Use piece of Image

What I want is all procedure worked by Script

Comment: What does the error says?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`TextureImporter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureImporter.html) belongs to the `UnityEditor` namespace which doesn't exist in a built app but only within the Unity Editor itself. → You can not use this!

---

What you can do is using  [`Sprite.Create`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html) to generate a sprite from a given `Texture2D`.

### Cropping

If it is actually only about cutting out a certain part of the texture to use it as sprite than you only need to define in the `rect` parameter the part of the texture you want to use from that image.

```
// Wherever you get the texture from
Texture texture = ...;
       
// E.g. for using the center of the image
// but half of the size
var rect = new Rect(texture.width / 4, texture.height / 4, texture.width / 2, texture.height / 2);

// Create the sprite
var sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, rect, Vector2.one * 0.5f);
```

where [`rect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite-rect.html) is the

> Location of the Sprite on the original Texture, specified in pixels.

---

### Slicing

If you additionally want a slicing border (which you usually define in the `Sprite Editor` within Unity) there is an overload of `Sprite.Create` that additionally takes a `border` parameter e.g.

```
var borders = new Vector4(2, 2, 2, 2);
var sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, rect, Vector2.one * 0.5f, 100, SpriteMeshType.FullRect, borders);
```

where [`border`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite-border.html)

> Returns the border sizes of the sprite.

> X=left, Y=bottom, Z=right, W=top.

API doesn't say it but I guess like the `rect` values those values are also in pixels.

Comment: Thanks I solved that problem similar idea but, your tips(?) solution is better than me I add my code under your answer :)

Comment: There is an additional `extrude` parameter before the `SpriteMeshType.FullRect`. Can be set to 0.

Comment: What if I want to use that sprite returned by Sprite.Create to assign to a animation clip? Do I need to save it first?

Comment: @ZonyZhao what do you mean? In the example snippets I already store it in the `var sprite` so you can pass it on to store it somewhere else in the way you like to

Comment: @derHugo As far as I know, the sprite returned in your code is a runtime sprite. What I was trying to implement is create a sprite in editor-time file and assign it to animation clip.

Comment: @ZonyZhao for an editor script it gets a bit more complex since you will have to literally create the sprite **asset** via [`AssetDatabase.CreateAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.CreateAsset.html) and save it

Answer (score 1):

I solved using rect and Sprite Rnederer
here is my code

```
void Start()
{

    rect = new Rect(0f, 0f, 255, 255);
    this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite.Create(img, rect, new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
    this.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = new Vector3(100, 100, 0);
    StartCoroutine(Update());
}

/*
 *  rect = new Rect(i, 0, 255, 255);
        this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite.Create(img, rect, new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));*/

IEnumerator Update()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (i < 1000)
        {
            i += 255;
            if (i > 770)
            {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);
        rect = new Rect(i, 0f, 255, 255);
        this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite.Create(img, rect, new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the idea using the `rect` parameter stays basically the same ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I update entire code with a reset button and positing automaticly.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Linq;


public class LevelGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Space(15)]
    [Header("-----Level Props")]
    [Space(15)]
    [SerializeField] private int _Level;
    [SerializeField] private int _TexturePixelPerUnit;
    [SerializeField] private Texture2D _Puzzle_Sprite;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2Int _Level_Size;

    [Space(15)]
    [Header("-----Level Objects")]
    [Space(15)]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _Parent;
    public void CreateLevel()
    {
        print("Level Creating");
        _Parent.name = "Level" + _Level.ToString();
        var spriteSizeX = _Puzzle_Sprite.width / _Level_Size.x;
        var spriteSizeY =  _Puzzle_Sprite.height / _Level_Size.y;
        var sideSize = 5.1145f / _Level_Size.x;
        var unitPer2 = sideSize / 2;
        FolderCreator.CreateEmptyFolder(_Level.ToString());
        AssetDatabase.Refresh();
        for (int y = 0; y < _Level_Size.y; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < _Level_Size.x; x++)
            {
                GameObject piece = new GameObject();
                piece.name = "Piece" + x + y;
                piece.transform.SetParent(_Parent.transform);
                piece.transform.tag = "Line";
                piece.transform.position = new Vector3((sideSize * x - unitPer2) - (unitPer2 / _Level_Size.x), sideSize * y - unitPer2);
                var rect = new Rect(x * spriteSizeX, y * spriteSizeY, spriteSizeX, spriteSizeY);
                var sprite = Sprite.Create(_Puzzle_Sprite, rect, Vector2.one * 0.5f, _TexturePixelPerUnit);
                piece.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprite;
                AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(sprite, $"Assets/Levels/Level{_Level}/Photo{x}{y}.asset");
            }
        }
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
        AssetDatabase.Refresh();
    }

    public void ResetLevel(){
        List<GameObject> _pieces_ = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Line").ToList();
        _pieces_?.ForEach((__piece__)=>{DestroyImmediate(__piece__);});
    }
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(LevelGenerator))]
public class LevelGeneratorEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Do Level"))
        {
            LevelGenerator levelGenerator = (LevelGenerator)target;
            levelGenerator.CreateLevel();
        }
        if(GUILayout.Button("Reset"))
        {
            LevelGenerator levelGenerator = (LevelGenerator)target;
            levelGenerator.ResetLevel();
        }
    }
}
```