# Unity 3D - Dynamically 'slicing' background image

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, background, slice, mask

I'm fairly new to Unity and not quite sure how to handle this problem.

I have two images, one has clouds on it (day) and one has stars on it (night). What I want to do is show the clouds in the top of my scene and the stars on the bottom. There is a ground object in the middle of the screen where the player will be walking on, this should be the dividing line between the two images. The ground however is not one straight line but can have height differences.

The "solution" I came up with is to use the ground object(s) to slice the images so it kinda serves as a dividing line. But not sure if this is even possible. Maybe I could do something with 2 different camera's or mask the images somehow.. (Just throwing my own thoughts in here as well) I'll be fumbling around with these things in between and try to keep the topic up to date with what I tried.

I put in an attachment to (hopefully) make it more clear.

Greets,
Lukie

attachment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGaLO.jpg

Comment: One of them (night sky or day sky) can first be displayed on the full screen, as an image background.

Then, for the other part, use a dynamic generated mesh/2D sprite.

Comment: Thank for thinking with me here, I tried this a bit but rendering a dynamic mesh has been really rough for me. Gonna try something different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to slice sprite by script ?(not use Editor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55738954/how-to-slice-sprite-by-script-not-use-editor)

Answer (score 0):

The first solution to my mind was preparing a tileset. If you're not going to design a different section every time. So if you're not going to do a computer design. You can do it yourself by adjusting the size.

You can also dynamically generate the stars with the -y axis of the ground object and the clouds with the + y-axis. You can use instantiate function

Example:

```
public GameObject clouds;
public GameObject stars;
// Start is called before the first frame update
private void Awake()
{
    Instantiate(clouds, new Vector3(this.transform.position.x, this.transform.position.y + 3.625f, this.transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate(stars, new Vector3(this.transform.position.x, this.transform.position.y  - 3.625f, this.transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Of course, the background design that you will use here must be sustainable.

[Dynamic Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aipyz.png)

Comment: This one really helped me, just instantiating new objects by using the ground position has been pretty easy and it seems to work fine for now. Thanks for thinking with me here, the solution was easier than I thought it would be!