# Screenshot from a rendertexture (non-main camera) to fit sprite (in 3D space) exactly - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do you adjust or otherwise set up a screenshot to have the exact dimensions of a particular sprite that is in 3D space (so, Gameobject with SpriteRenderer).

The render camera is set up directly above the sprite but has some blank space outside the boundaries of the sprite. I'm not sure how to precisely adjust the viewport of the rendercamera.

Here's what the scene looks like. (Actually this is a quick and simplified version of my current scene, to showcase my specific problem) And yes, I'm trying to take a specific screenshot at runtime. The main camera is at an arbitrary angle but the render camera can be centered to the sprite renderer. In other words, the screenshot I am taking looks like the one in the Camera Preview in bottom right corner in the pic below. How do I crop out (or adjust the viewport to exclude) the extra part beyond the size of the sprite renderer?

[image]

Comment: would maybe [cropping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55739620/7111561) the texture to the correct size help? In general please add your code so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can you maybe show with some screenshots what is happening now, and what you would like to happen?

Comment: @derHugo not necessarily as i am trying to crop the sprite itself. i'm trying to take a screenshot in 3D world space though from a top down camera centered on the sprite renderer - and not 2D space

Comment: updated with some setup screenshots that may try to clarify this multi-camera situation

Comment: Is it an option to make the camera `Orthographic` ?

Comment: ideally, no since the 3D game objects look different in orth vs perspective... but if the only solution to get the cropping properly done is to, then i guess we would have to?

Comment: Have you tried to read [bounds.extents](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds-extents.html), fighting against `Perspective` is a real headache, I had these problems several months ago and I preferred to used `Orthographic` view...

Comment: @ina is the camera always going to be placed along the sprite's normal from its midpoint?

Comment: @ina did you find a good solution to this?

Comment: i wasn't able to get your solution to work... were you working with a sprite renderer instead of a quad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [calculate](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/FrustumSizeAtDistance.html) the size of the frustum in world space:

```
float frustumHeight = 2.0f * distance * Mathf.Tan(camera.fieldOfView * 0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
float frustrumWidth = frustumHeight * camera.aspect;
```

Then if you know the painting's height and width in world units, you can calculate how big of the center piece of the screen it's occupying:

```
float widthPortion = paintingWidth / frustrumWidth;
float heightPortion = paintingHeight / frustrumHeight;
```

Then you know how much of the center of the renderTexture to hide:

```
float leftRightCrop = (1f-widthPortion)/2f;
float topBottomCrop = (1f-heightPortion)/2f;
```

So to copy it from your camera's render texture you can do this in `OnPostRender`:

```
RenderTexture currentRT = RenderTexture.active;
RenderTexture.active = Cam.targetTexture;
 
Cam.Render();

int croppedPixelWidth = widthPortion*camera.pixelWidth;
int croppedPixelHeight = heightPortion*camera.pixelHeight;

int leftPixelPadding = leftRightCrop*camera.pixelWidth;
int bottomPixelPadding = topBottomCrop*camera.pixelHeight;

Texture2D cropped = new Texture2D(croppedPixelWidth, croppedPixelHeight);
cropped.ReadPixels(new Rect(
        leftPixelPadding, 
        bottomPixelPadding, 
        leftPixelPadding + croppedPixelWidth, 
        bottomPixelPadding + croppedPixelHeight), 0, 0);

cropped.Apply();

RenderTexture.active = currentRT;
```

Or as @ina used it,

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class SpritePerfectScreenshot : MonoBehaviour
{

    bool ScreenshotIt;
    float widthPortion; float heightPortion;
    float leftRightCrop; float topBottomCrop;
    Camera camera;

    public void TakeScreencap(Camera c,float distance,float pw,float ph)
    {
        camera = c;c.enabled = true;

        SetItUp(distance, pw, ph);
    }

    void SetItUp(float distance,float paintingWidth,float paintingHeight)
    {
        float frustrumHeight = 2.0f * distance * Mathf.Tan(camera.fieldOfView * 0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        float frustrumWidth = frustrumHeight * camera.aspect;

          widthPortion =  (paintingWidth / frustrumWidth);
          heightPortion = (paintingHeight / frustrumHeight);

          leftRightCrop =   (1f -  widthPortion) / 2f;
          topBottomCrop =  (1f -  heightPortion) / 2f;


        ScreenshotIt = true;
        print("SetItUp " + distance);
    }

    private void OnPostRender()
    {
        if (ScreenshotIt)
        {
            int croppedPixelWidth =(int) (widthPortion * camera.pixelWidth);
            int croppedPixelHeight =(int) (heightPortion * camera.pixelHeight);

            int leftPixelPadding =(int)( leftRightCrop * camera.pixelWidth);
            int bottomPixelPadding =(int)( topBottomCrop * camera.pixelHeight);

            print(croppedPixelWidth + " " + croppedPixelHeight);

            Texture2D cropped = new Texture2D(croppedPixelWidth, croppedPixelHeight);
            cropped.ReadPixels(new Rect(
        leftPixelPadding,
        bottomPixelPadding,
        leftPixelPadding + croppedPixelWidth,
        bottomPixelPadding + croppedPixelHeight), 0, 0);
            cropped.Apply();

            string uuid = UUID.GetUUID(); string localPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + uuid + ".png";

#if !UNITY_EDITOR
            NativeGallery.SaveImageToGallery(cropped.EncodeToPNG(), "A Beautiful Letter",uuid);
#else
            File.WriteAllBytes(localPath,cropped.EncodeToPNG());
            print(localPath);
#endif 

            //TODO server (?)

            ScreenshotIt = false;camera.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi! i think the issue might be because the image quad might not be in the right unity scale units?

Comment: actually i'm not sure if i'm implementing the region properly in the final readpixel.....

Comment: `Texture2D image = new Texture2D(camera.targetTexture.width, camera.targetTexture.height); `

Comment: ` image.ReadPixels(new Rect(camera.pixelWidth * leftRightCrop * 0.25f, camera.pixelHeight * topBottomCrop*0.25f, leftRightCrop * camera.pixelWidth, topBottomCrop * camera.pixelHeight), 0, 0);  `

Comment: @ina I edited my answer to include how to use it at the bottom. I also changed the `___Crop` variables to be more useful so be sure to notice those changes.

Comment: @ina did you have any further problems with this answer?

Comment: is there a typo in croppedPixelHeight calculation

Comment: @ina looks like it. I think I fixed it

Comment: Texture has out of range width / height

Comment: @ina world units aka meters. Also I just realized there was another typo in the `ReadPixels` line. Try if that works for you

Comment: how do you convert photo dimensions to meters

Comment: you don't. You get the size of the spriterenderer/quad in world meters. The pixel size of the photo is irrelevant.

Comment: hmmm how do you get the size of the sprite renderer quad in world meters (?)

Comment: @ina try [`SpriteRenderer.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer.html)

Comment: Cool finally got it to work! https://gist.github.com/yosun/daa166bdac92cfcaba350ec1bb4e6e06

Comment: @ina if it's like a single pixel or two, it might be due to rounding errors, maybe make the increase the rect start by 1-2 pixels and decrease the size by double that?

Comment: it seems to be device screen dependent - i fudged it to work on unity editor but on iphone it does that etc

Comment: hmm actually I think it may be due to multiple cameras and OnPostRender - does the script need to be on the actual specific camera or can it be on the Camera.main?

Comment: @ina it can be attached to any gameobject. I think I understand the problem and to fix it I think you need to swap out the active render texture to the one on the camera. I edited the answer to include that. If that doesn't work, it might be best to ask a separate question.

Comment: OnPostRender needs to be attached to a Camera though right

Comment: @ina oh, yes you're right. It would probably be best to put it on the camera you're capturing for the image but in practice (unless you're moving things after one camera renders and before another one does in the same frame, a pretty unusual thing) it probably won't matter, and any gameobject with an actively rendering camera would work the same.