# is it possible in Unity to slice image from the middle?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, sprite, texture2d

I get an image from the backend which I want to put in a puzzle shuffle game, however right now it is cropping from left to almost middle of the image , I would like to crop the center of the image, I was trying to use another Sprite which I cropped to the middle then use it in the `ImageSlicer` however I am getting same results.
Here are the images :

[Main Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkzeK.png) , [Cropped Image as temp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjhMh.png) , [Sliced Image as imagesSlices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUrYl.png)

am I doing the right thing and maybe I'm messing something in the code or this isn't how I should crop and slice ?

```
Sprite temp = Sprite.Create(currentImage, new Rect(currentImage.width * 0.25f, 0, currentImage.width * 0.75f, currentImage.height),new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);

Texture2D[,] imageSlices = ImageSlicer.GetSlices(temp.texture, blocksPerLine);
```

Comment: Would this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55739620/7111561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the texture was staying the same and I was trying to get a new sprite not a new texture but I need a new cropped texture to work with which is why the sliced images were taken from old texture.